# Obx is not working - Flutter Getx package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

The value of the model fields is changing but the widget is not updating. When I renavigate to the screen then the widget is updating. I would like to update two widgets. When I use GetBuilder() Screen x updates but the trailing Text widget doesn't. The code is as follows.

Getx Controller:

```
  late Rx<TeamBetModel> displayModel = TeamBetModel().obs;

  void setDMValues(TeamBetModel? tm) {
    displayModel.value.t1Goals = tm!.t1Goals;
    print('++ ${displayModel.value.t1Goals}');
  }
```

Screen x

```
                        Obx(
                          () => Text(
                            _savebetcontroller.displayModel.value.t1Goals ==
                                    null
                                ? '-'
                                : _savebetcontroller.displayModel.value.t1Goals
                                    .toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 90.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

```
class BetItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  //
  BetItemWidget_Fields _betItemWidget_Fields = BetItemWidget_Fields();

  //
  BetBottomSheet _betBottomSheet = BetBottomSheet();

  //
  final _saveBetController = Get.find<SaveBetController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List? trailStringList = [
      // #1
      _saveBetController.displayModel.value.t1Goals == null
          ? null
          : _saveBetController.displayModel.value.t1Goals.toString(),
      // #2
      _saveBetController.displayModel.value.t1YellowCards == null
          ? null
          : _saveBetController.displayModel.value.t1YellowCards.toString(),
     
    ];
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _betItemWidget_Fields.statList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                _betBottomSheet.betBottomSheetFN(
                  title: _betItemWidget_Fields.statList[index],
                  index: index,
                );
              },
              leading: Text(
                _betItemWidget_Fields.statList[index],
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),

// Want to update trailing too
              trailing: Text(
                trailStringList[index] == null ? '-' : trailStringList[index],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I switched to GetBuilder

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping your trailing text widget with Obx as well:

```
trailing: Obx(() => Text(
                trailStringList[index] == null ? '-' : trailStringList[index],
              ),
)
```